# Sum combinations that add up to a given natural number

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I've been struggling  with this pretty tricky problem for the past week :( I have to find all combinations of numbers that sum up to a given natural number using recursion. I'm not allowed to use LINQ or anything else besides "using system"

For example if the input is 7 then the output should look like this:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 2 + 1
3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
3 + 2 + 1 + 1
3 + 2 + 2
3 + 3 + 1
4 + 1 + 1 + 1
4 + 2 + 1
4 + 3
5 + 1 + 1
5 + 2
6 + 1
```

The numbers from the combination should be listed exactly in that order so for an input of 3 for example the output should be exactly as follows:

```
1 + 1 + 1
2 + 1
```

For an input of 4 the output should look like this:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 1 + 1
2 + 2
3 + 1
```

For every new list of combinations we increment the first number in the list and then we continue with the remaining part of the previous list until the sum will be equal with the input.

Just positive numbers are allowed between 1 (1 included) and input - 1.

My code so far gives me the following output for the same given input of 7:

```
+ 1
 + 1 + 1 + 2
 + 1 + 1 + 1
 + 2 + 2 + 3
 + 1 + 1 + 1
 + 1 + 1 + 2
 + 2 + 1
 + 1 + 1 + 2
 + 2 + 2 + 1
 + 3 + 3 + 4
 + 1 + 1 + 1
 + 1 + 1 + 2
 + 1 + 1 + 1
 + 2 + 2 + 3
 + 2 + 1
 + 1 + 1 + 2
 + 1 + 1 + 1
 + 2 + 2 + 3
...
```

Can you please help me with some suggestions?

```
static string GenerateCombinations(int n)        
{
    string combinationList = "";

    for (int index = 1; index < n - 1; index++)
    {
        string intermediaryList = GenerateCombinations(n - index, index) + " + " + index;

        combinationList += intermediaryList;
    }

    return combinationList + "\n";
}

static string GenerateCombinations(int n, int index)
{
    string combinationList = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i <= index)
        {
            string intermediaryList = GenerateCombinations(n) + " + " + index;

            combinationList += intermediaryList;
        }
    }

    return combinationList;
}

static void Main()
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(GenerateCombinations(n));
}
```

Comment: If the input is 4, you want output that is 7? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: "For example if the input is 4 " Seems like your input was 7, at least from the example.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post now, I meant if the input is 7, the code should return all possible combinations that sum up to a final sum of 7, every list of combinations on a new line

Comment: The numbers from the combination should be bigger than 0. So everything between 1 (1 included) and n - 1 should be listed as a list of sum numbers

Comment: @BogdanMuscari, please put any additional important information in the question itself, rather than in a comment. (But I admit it should be obvious anyway.) Also, welcome to StackOverflow. You're doing well on your first question, unlike most newcomers here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will add the info in the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution not using collections (only `using System;`) and generating the output in the required order.

```cs
public static void PrintCombinations(int n)
{
    PrintRest("", 0, n, n - 1);
}

private static void PrintRest(string listStart, int startSum, int n, int max)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        string list = listStart.Length > 0
            ? listStart + " + " + i.ToString()
            : i.ToString();
        int sum = startSum + i;
        if (sum == n) {
            Console.WriteLine(list);
        } else if (sum < n) {
            PrintRest(list, sum, n, i);
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it as

```cs
PrintCombinations(7);
```

It starts by taking all possible start summands and calling itself to construct the rest of the sum. The combinations up to the current point are passed as string parameter `listStart`. The sum it represents is passed as `int startSum`. The target sum is `n`. `max` is the biggest summand allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> combinationList = new List<string>();
        const int SUM = 7;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            GenerateCombinations(numbers, 0);
            combinationList.Sort();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", combinationList));

            Console.ReadLine();
          
        }
        static void GenerateCombinations(List<int> numbers, int sum)
        {
            int start = 1;
            if (numbers.Count > 0) start = numbers[0]; 
                
            for (int i = start; i <= SUM; i++)
            {
                int newSum = sum + i;
                
                if (newSum > SUM) break;
                
                List<int> newList = new List<int>(numbers);
                newList.Insert(0,i);

                if (newSum == SUM)
                {
                    combinationList.Add(string.Join(" + ", newList));
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    GenerateCombinations(newList, newSum);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why should they try it? How does it work? Please walk OP (and other future visitors) through your logic. `SUM` should be a parameter rather than a global. Also, the output doesn't match OP's requested output.

Comment: Is this with LINQ? I'm not allowed to use anything else besides the using system. but thank you for this, I'm trying to understand the logic behind your answer, thank you again.

Comment: There is no linq.  I'm using using System.Collections.Generic; for the list of numbers.  can easily be changed to an array.

Comment: It gives me a wrong output unfortunately :( but thank you a lot

Comment: The answer is correct.  Maybe you need to use the vertical scroll bar to see all the results. I added picture of results

Comment: I don't think you're looking at OP's output very carefully. OP's output is sorted in a different way, and your output contains ascending and descending combinations while OP needs descending only. You're producing a ton of extra results that shouldn't be there, clearly visible from the screenshot. Also, [please don't post images when text will do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: I made a couple of minor changes to get same results as OP.  The request was vague. It did not say to remove duplicates and order was a requirement.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you still have 7 in the output, but that's a minor nitpick. Why not add an explanation? It seems more beneficial to teach your readers to fish rather than to simply give them a fish.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a recursive solution, let's do it recursively without *Linq* and other mean.

Let's start from the basic: when given `0`, we have an empty solution:

```
    private static int[][] Solutions(int value) {
      if (value <= 0)
        return new int[][] { new int[0] };

      //TODO: other cases for 1, 2, ... 
    }
```

Time to do the next step: if we know how to solve for some `n - 1` (`n - 1 >= 0`) we can solve for `n` as follow:
all solutions start from `m` (`m < n`) are in form

```
`m + solutions for n - m which uses m .. 1 only`
```

E.g.

```
6 + 1                      <- starts from 6, solves for 7 - 6 = 1, uses 6..1 only 
5 + 2                      ...
5 + 1 + 1
4 + 3
4 + 2 + 1
4 + 1 + 1 + 1              ... 
3 + 3 + 1                  <- starts from 3, solves for 7 - 3 = 4, uses 3..1 only
3 + 2 + 2                  <- starts from 3, solves for 7 - 3 = 4, uses 3..1 only 
3 + 2 + 1 + 1              <- starts from 3, solves for 7 - 3 = 4, uses 3..1 only
3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1          ...
2 + 2 + 2 + 1
2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1      ... 
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1  <- starts from 1, solves for 7 - 1 = 6, uses 1..1 only
```

This recursion can be encoded as

```
    private static int[][] Solutions(int value, int startWith = -1) {
      if (value <= 0)
        return new int[][] { new int[0] };

      if (startWith < 0)
        startWith = value - 1;

      List<int[]> solutions = new List<int[]>();

      for (int i = Math.Min(value, startWith); i >= 1; --i) 
        foreach (int[] solution in Solutions(value - i, i)) {
          int[] next = new int[solution.Length + 1];

          Array.Copy(solution, 0, next, 1, solution.Length);
          next[0] = i;

          solutions.Add(next);
        }
      
      // Or just (if we are allow a bit of Linq)
      //   return solutions.ToArray();
      int[][] answer = new int[solutions.Count][];

      for (int i = 0; i < solutions.Count; ++i)
        answer[i] = solutions[i];

      return answer;
    }
```

**Demo**

```
var result = Solutions(7);

// A pinch of Linq for demonstration
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(solution => string.Join(" + ", solution)));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
6 + 1
5 + 2
5 + 1 + 1
4 + 3
4 + 2 + 1
4 + 1 + 1 + 1
3 + 3 + 1
3 + 2 + 2
3 + 2 + 1 + 1
3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 2 + 1
2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```